# Input from forms can't execute .bat file

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file

Hi everyone I've been creating this program for a day now. But it seems that I can't get it to work. What I want is, I have a windows form, who will get the IP address input and will execute a .bat file.

```
@echo off
wmic /node:x computersystem get username
```

where x is the string variable for my IP.
the command will print out the current logged in username.

Here's my c# code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace wmic_forms
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string x;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = "C:\\ken.bat";
        Process p = Process.Start(psi);
        string strOutput = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        //p.WaitForExit();
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.Arguments = textBox1.Text;

        MessageBox.Show(strOutput);
        //Console.WriteLine(strOutput);
        //Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //my input text box for IP
        x = textBox1.Text;
    }
  }
}
```

The code runs with no error. But it would only print out the entire strings from .bat file. Please give me feedback on how can I pass variable x to .bat file and execute its command.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a batch file to do that, simply run `wmic` with those parameters. And you especially don't need to follow malware practices of storing files in system folders, like the C: drive.

As to the specific problem in your code, you're setting the process object's properties *after* you launch it instead of before. Of course they don't matter anymore.

And while we're on the topic of refactoring, I'll remind you that it's not 1985 anymore to launch chains of scripts because the OS doesn't expose its inner workings. You can easily access the WMI API directly from C# using managed classes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementscope(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi Blindy-- thank you for your swift response. RIght now, I am experimenting c#-->bat-->c# method in order to know the concept behind it. As I said I'm still a beginner and want to do things the hard way. But thank you for your suggestions, I will try this out, executing the command directly. Will let you know the output. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: "As to the specific problem in your code, you're setting the process object's properties after you launch it instead of before. Of course they don't matter anymore."   ----- Can you give me the particular line of the code? Thank you :)

Comment: The process structure is used by `Process.Start`, any changes you do to it afterwards are useless -- and those changes enable stdout redirection, which is why you're not getting anything from it. Again though, you should be using WMI queries directly, not launching other scripts to do the same thing.

Comment: Already edited my code. And I think it's already doing what it supposed to do. But I think my input from form is not passed on the bat file, does it says, "node-x , error, description:.." any feedback from this?

Comment: They're not passed, because as I said before you add them to the structure after you create the process. You keep ignoring that. Besides your batch file never uses arguments passed to it.